Properties Penal disappeared in Layout Mode
my Properties Panel except for the Material one disappeared in the Layout Mode and I dont know why.

( ive selected a normal Mesh object)

you can go to preferences and in the hamburger menu in the bottom left click on Load Factory Preferences to reset your layout

it didnt work unfortunately but thanks for the help

You have pinned the Material Properties panel. A pinned panel remains visible, regardless of which tab has been selected, but all other panels are hidden.
Display settings are stored for each Workspace. A pinned panel in workspace Layout is displayed in Modeling as long as the panel is not also pinned in this workspace.
manual panel pin
Activate the Material Panel and click on the pinning icon in the top right corner to unpin the panel.


Thank you so much for the help. It worked
